# Connect to WPA3 network using wpa_cli

Tags: wpa

I'm trying to connect my device to a WPA3 network using wpa supplicant. I've had success connecting to WPA2 using the following settings:

```
>add_network
>set_network 0 ssid "myssid"
>set_network 0 psk "password"
>enable 0
```

After that I am able to see that my device was able to connect to a WPA2 network. I connected to my WPA3 network without wpa_cli and inspected the configuration file and saw:

```
network={
    ssid="myssid"
    scan_ssid=1
    psk=2f6ec8e66bd919f1ce670f15d2e6c18f3a5444394c25e18bea29c67895afb023
    sae_password="password"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=SAE
    pairwise=CCMP
    ieee80211w=2
}
```

So I thought I'd be able to connect with the following commands:

```
>add_network
>set_network 0 ssid "myssid"
>set_network 0 key_mgmt SAE
>set_network 0 sae_password "password"
>enable 0
```

but I keep getting a <3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND message. I tried checking the scan_results and the network I'm trying to connect to is showing up:

```
>scan_results
bssid / frequency / signal level / flags / ssid
00:11:32:a5:8a:97       5745    -28     [WPA2-SAE-CCMP][WPS][ESS]       myssid
```

I'm unsure why it's not able to connect to this network even though everything seems to be configured correctly. I can connect to this network normally without wpa_cli, is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Setting `log_level DEBUG` in **wpa_cli** helps in these cases.

Comment: I did have debug logging enabled, the only thing I was getting out of it was `<3>CTRL-EVENT-NETWORK-NOT-FOUND `, I found the solution though.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out, just had to run the following for it to start working:

```
set_network ieee80211w 2
```

Quickly connected without problems after that.